# How to explicitly command MacOS to query external monitor resolution?

Tags: macbook-pro, big-sur, resolution

A [MacBook Air 2014](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP700?locale=en_US) outfitted with Big Sur and a single [2560X1440 (2K) monitor](https://www.bestbuy.com/site/hp-pavilion-32-led-qhd-monitor-displayport-hdmi-black/6343305.p?skuId=6343305) via HDMI.   Apple indicates:

Intel HD Graphics 5000
Dual display and video mirroring: Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display and up to 2560 by 1600 pixels on an external display, both at millions of colors
Thunderbolt digital video output

Resolution is output at 1080.  How does one command the machine to provide a 2560X1440 resolution option?

Is there a test that can be performed to eliminate the cable as the bottleneck?

Comment: According to Apple's specs that Mac supports *"...up to 2560 by 1600" (EG not 1440)* Sometimes getting different resolutions requires the use of a 3rd party utility like SwitchResX or the like

Comment: @SteveChambers   Thanks for the reply.   I am using a pair of said monitors on Catalina Desktop

Comment: The way I am reading this https://support.apple.com/kb/SP700?locale=en_US is that it will support **up to** that resolution on a (single) external monitor. It *may* support two monitors but the combined resolution of both need to be less than or equal to that resolution.

Comment: @SteveChambers  Clarification: I am successfully running a pair of said monitors on Catalina.   The MacBook is connected to only one monitor.